# Location of localhost folder in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I'm running eclipse Juno, with Tomcat 7.0.29. I have some files that are saved to the root of the webapp by my webapp and I want to delete them. I'm trying to find the localhost folder in order to be able to do this. Everything I'm reading tells me it should be at /var/www, however there is not /www directory in var. Where could it be?

Comment: Where's your tomcat installation path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Eclipse IDE and you don't know where your Tomcat installation folder is, you can find it using the IDE by going to *Windows/Preferences*. It will pop a Preferences window, select the *Server/Runtime Environment* option in the left tree, in the right side must appear *Apache Tomcat v7.x*. Select it from the list and select the *Edit...* option, it will show you the tomcat installation directory. Let's call this folder `<tomcat>`

Now you know the folder installation, but maybe Eclipse is not using it to deploy the Java Web applications. To make sure of this, in your Eclipse, go to the *Servers* view (if it's not visible in the IDE, go to *Window/Show view/Servers*), it will show you your tomcat server (and others), double click on it. In the Tomcat overview window, check the *Server locations* panel, expand it and check where the webapp is deployed:

- If selected option is *Use Tomcat installation* then the web app must be in *`<tomcat>`webapps*
- If selected option is *Use workspace metadata* then the web app must be in your workspace inside *.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp[number]/wtpwebapps* (thanks to [Lars Vogel blog post](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2009/04/08/eclipse-wtp-deployment-location-of-the-local-tomcat/)). This is a special folder created by Eclipse.

Comment: While this answer led me to conclusion what my final solution turned out to be was that my browser cache needed emptying. It wasn't that the files were being stored or not overwritten, it was just that they were in the browser cache (they were images).

Comment: @user1584500 well, that was unexpected. When I make my tests, I tend to use chrome, firefox and IE (last one is not my favorite but some people still use it).

Answer (score 0):

Default tomcat folder is at /var/lib/tomcat7. Your webapps are under /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps

Not sure what localhost folder you are referring to. There is /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost but I dont see a reason why you should be touching it.

This assumes you used standard Ubuntu tools to install tomcat.

Comment: This depends how OP has installed tomcat. Maybe he/she just download it from internet as a tar.gz file and uncompressed it somewhere else.

Comment: There's not tomcat directory in /var. I haven't changed the default as far as I'm aware, could it be anywhere else?

Comment: @user1584500 in your Eclipse, go to Windows/Preferences. It will open a window, check in the left tree for Server/Runtime Environment, then it will appear Apache Tomcat v7.x. Select it from the list and select the *Edit...* option, it will show you the tomcat installation directory.

Comment: OP states this is Ubuntu 12, and has not changed the default. Note its /var/lib/tomcat7 - not /var/tomcat7. You used apt-get to install tomcat?

Comment: I can find this folder ok, but it doesn't contain my webapp nor the files I'm trying to delete.

Comment: I can access the files using http://localhost/webappname/filename.ext. I'm just trying to find where they are and delete them.

Comment: Did you install tomcat with apt-get?

Comment: @user1584500 in your Eclipse, go to the *Servers* view, it will show you your tomcat server, double click on it. In the Tomcat overview window, check the *Server locations* panel, expand it and check where the webapp is deployed. If selected option is *Use Tomcat installation*, then the webapp must be in *<tomcat_installation_folder>/webapps*, otherwise it must be in your workspace inside an special folder created by Eclipse (I'm not sure about this last one).

Comment: @rootkit007 not all the Ubuntu (nor linux) users will install apps using apt-get or any other OS tool. You must consider this when submitting future answers :).

Comment: It's using workspace metadata. It must be something to do with this folder no being cleaned properly. Thanks.

Comment: @user1584500 you're welcome. I'll post an answer based on my comments.

Comment: If you are starting Tomcat from Eclipse then indeed your webapp will be located in workspace, as Luiggi correctly surmised. You provide the path to Tomcat installation when defining the server runtime in Eclipse, and your webapp should be under there