# How to see output of System.out.println with a servlet using Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I need to see the output from a servlet and I'm using `System.out.println`.
I have heard that I can't see the log into the console but only in C:\Users\Samuel\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\logs
but this folder is empty. I have checked the path with right click on the server/server_path. How can I see the output?

Comment: Please review this: [Location of locahost folder in Ubuntu 12.04](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14984586/1065197)

Answer (score 0):

The `System.out.println()` should print to the console while the program runs..
If you want it in a file, go to:

```
Run as>Run Configurations>Common
```

And set Standard output to a file of your choice in any directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you manage the servlet's container through eclipse, then eclipse will open a console view that displays the System.out and System.err output.

If you don't see the console window, you can always open a new one by going to the menu bar and clicking Window->Show View->Other, then selecting Console from the list.